# ASP.NET Zero + ASP.NET Boilerplate template folder hierarchy/usage

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I am looking for an explanation of the templating folder structure.
If someone can point me at some documentation, that would be awesome — I have looked but couldn't find it.

```
src/AppName.Application
src/AppName.Application.Client
src/AppName.Application.Shared
src/AppName.Core
src/AppName.Core.Shared
src/AppName.EntityFrameworkCore
src/AppName.Migrator .            # My understanding is that this if for performing database migrations
src/AppName.Mobile.Droid .        # This obviously hosts Android Mobile Code
src/AppName.Mobile.iOS .          # This obviously hosts iOS Mobile Code
src/AppName.Mobile.Shared         # This obviously hosts Shared Mobile Code
src/AppName.Web.Core              
src/AppName.Web.Host              
src/AppName.Web.Mvc               # This obviously is where the Mvc code goes
src/AppName.Web.Public            # Should this have all static css/js type files?
```

Basically, I don't know what the various parts are supposed to contain. Any help would be useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aspnetboilerplate tries to seperate everything

consider this url [NLayered Architecture](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/NLayer-Architecture)

- src/AppName.Application            ----> Api - code , available to the outside world, autmaticly build by the appname.web.host using swagger
- src/AppName.Application.Client     ----> a client implementing the api for your mobile app.
- src/AppName.Application.Shared     ----> all interfaces and dtos are defined here.
- src/AppName.Core                   ----> your business classes(or class model) including domain managers
- src/AppName.Core.Shared            ----> all your interfaces defining domain managers
- src/AppName.EntityFrameworkCore    ----> ORM
- src/AppName.Migrator               ----> console application for migrating database adjustments on all tenant databases.
- src/AppName.Mobile.Droid .
- src/AppName.Mobile.iOS .
- src/AppName.Mobile.Shared
- src/AppName.Web.Core              ----> you have chosen .net core and as such you can deploy without iis via this project
- src/AppName.Web.Host              ----> the api build upon appname.application
- src/AppName.Web.Mvc               ----> your front end application
- src/AppName.Web.Public            ----> just a second application for advertising your product before registering.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer, in the case of deploying without IIS would you have to do this via the `src/AppName.Web.Core`? Currently we are publishing the Mvc application only (not with IIS) and I am unsure of the implications of doing so - Any links etc. would be very helpful! Thanks again.

Comment: IIs is an application(or web) server, it adds alot of benefits, like routing and stuff. If you do it without iis, then i assume you are using kestrel. wich is a standard for .net core. Best do some research regarding kestrel. My knowledge is quite limited regarding that.